# Looping through multi dimensional array when Key changes each time PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Getting back into basic PHP recently and have a stumbling block that I can't seem to get past with a **JSON** response. I have turned the response into an Array however the Array is multi-dimensional (I think!) and the Array I want to extract the values from changes its Key value each time so not sure on how to isolate this.

The array is below and the values I am looking to extract are the keyword (which keeps changing "garmin gps systems", "satmap gps systems" etc.), the Google position and URL associated to this.

```
    Array
    (
        [api] => cognitiveSEO API
        [data] => Array
            (
                [status] => success
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [2015-07-16] => Array
                            (
                                [garmin gps systems] => Array
                                    (
                                        [locale] => en-uk
                                        [google] => Array
                                            (
                                                [position] => 
                                                [url] => 
                                            )

                                        [bing] => Array
                                            (
                                                [position] => 8
                                                [url] => http://www.aboveandbeyond.co.uk/gps-and-navigation/gps-systems/garmin
                                            )

                                        [yahoo] => Array
                                            (
                                                [position] => 8
                                                [url] => http://www.aboveandbeyond.co.uk/gps-and-navigation/gps-systems/garmin
                                            )

                                    )

                                [satmap gps systems] => Array
                                    (
                                        [locale] => en-uk
                                        [google] => Array
                                            (
                                                [position] => 25
                                                [url] => http://www.aboveandbeyond.co.uk/gps-and-navigation/satmap
                                            )

                                        [bing] => Array
                                            (
                                                [position] => 4
                                                [url] => http://www.aboveandbeyond.co.uk/gps-and-navigation/gps-systems/satmap
                                            )

                                        [yahoo] => Array
                                            (
                                                [position] => 4
                                                [url] => http://www.aboveandbeyond.co.uk/gps-and-navigation/gps-systems/satmap
                                            )

                                    )
```

In terms of the code I have so far, I've managed to grab the JSON, turn it into an array and trying to print those values into a table using the **foreach** loop below but I am not sure how to reference the keyword value?;

```
    foreach($data as $rows) {
        echo '';
        echo ''.$rows['??'].'';
        echo ''.$rows['position'].'';
        echo ''.$rows['url'].'';
    }
```

Any help much appreciated, I havesearched high and low but have not been able to find anything so far.

Comment: I don't understand the question. There's only `position` and `url` and it doesn't seem to change between "garmin gps systems", "satmap gps systems", they are both within the same array. Could you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assign that array to `$arr` variable and iterate, assuming that there are numerous dates, in the following manner:

```
foreach ($arr['data']['data'] as $date => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $gps_key => $gps_data) {
        $final[$date][] = array(
            "key" => $gps_key,
            "position" => $gps_data['google']['position'],
            "url" => $gps_data['google']['url']
        );
    }
}

var_dump($final);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [2015-07-16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => garmin gps systems
                    [position] => 
                    [url] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => satmap gps systems
                    [position] => 
                    [url] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Great stuff, this works. Can you use the same loop to pull out ['position'] and ['url'] from the ['google'] array?

Comment: yeah.. question is where would you like to place the position/url once its pulled. should it go in the same final array?

Comment: My aim is to be able to access the keyword value which now works thanks to yourself! The position and URL values of the [google] array to display in a table - keyword column, position column and URL column.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. Try that out and let me know if it works

Comment: Perfect! added in the following to print it off into a table which seems to work foreach ($final[$date] as $rows) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$rows['key'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$rows['position'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$rows['url'].'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}

Answer (score 0):

Even with changing key values you can still iterate through using `$array[0]`,`$array[1]`, etc.